# application.properties override in HELM

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have following configMap and I need to override value of quarkus.http.port & quarkus.datasource.TEST.jdbc.url while deploying it UAT env. How to override it using values.yaml  ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: app-yaml
data:
  application.yml: |
    quarkus.http.port=8890
    quarkus.datasource.TEST.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define values in the `value.yaml` file,

```
quarkus:
  port: 8080
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/test
```

and the configmap should be consuming these value for `port` and `url`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: app-yaml
data:
  application.yml: |
    quarkus.http.port={{ .Values.quarkus.port }}
    quarkus.datasource.TEST.jdbc.url={{ .Values.quarkus.url }}
```